# make work an applet in a osgi bundle

Tags: applet, osgi

I would like to create a web application that performs some sort of animation of some bundle's activity inside an OSGI Framework. I'm using Equinox embedded in Tomcat through Servletbridge. I have tried to create an OSGI bundle that registers an HTML page (with an applet tag) using httpservice. The OSGI bundle contains a package with the applet class.

When I export the plugin project in the tomcat/webapps/bridge/WEB-INF/eclipse/plugin directory the jar content is:

```
META-INF
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
name/of/packages/.class files
home.html
```

In the activator class of this bundle I get an httpservice and register the home.html file as /home. When I start Tomcat and go to:

```
localhost:8080/bridge/home
```

The page loads, but I get a `ClassNotFoundException` on the applet, whereas opening the HTML page from the Jar archive the Applet load. How can I make it work?

edit:
home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet code="thesis.bot.wab.applet.DApplet.class" width="400" height="250"></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

src/thesis.bot.wab.Activator

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
private static boolean started=false;
HttpServiceTracker http;

public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("started");
    http = new HttpServiceTracker(context);
    http.open();
    started=true;
}

public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("stopped");
    started=false;
    http.close();
}

public static boolean isStarted(){
    return started;
}

private class HttpServiceTracker extends ServiceTracker {

    public HttpServiceTracker(BundleContext context) {
        super(context, HttpService.class.getName(), null);
    }

public Object addingService(ServiceReference reference) {
   HttpService httpService = (HttpService) context.getService(reference);
    try {   
    httpService.registerResources("/home", "/home.html", null);
    httpService.registerServlet("/servlet", new DServlet(context), null, null);
    } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
return httpService;
}       

public void removedService(ServiceReference reference, Object service) {
    HttpService httpService = (HttpService) service;
    httpService.unregister("/servlet"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    httpService.unregister("/home");
    super.removedService(reference, service);
        }
    }
}
```

edit: my purpose is to retrieve the bundlecontext and getting information about bundles to visualize them in the applet.

Comment: How do you define the url of the applet in the html? You should provide the jar or .class file as a resource during a HttpServletRequest.

Comment: are u saying that i should register as resource the applet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your browser downloads the html file. After it is downloaded, the browser checks the applet tag in the html. It starts a JVM that tries to download the applet from the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/bridge/thesis.bot.wab.applet.DApplet.class
```

However, nothing is there and why would be anything?

You should register the class file or the full jar file as a resource. After that, you should insert an applet tag into the html file that points to the jar or class file. In case your applet has any dependencies, those jars should be listed as well.

It is useful to switch on the Java console (google for it) and push the button "5" to have low level debug messages. There you will see the issues why your applet does not start (downloading urls, dependency issues...)

Comment: thank u very much! it works! i register the class file as resource with the line httpService.registerResources("/thesis/bot/wab/applet/DApplet.class", "thesis/bot/wab/applet/DApplet.class", null);

Comment: is it possible to register a directory serving all incoming request from the applet?

Comment: I do not think that you can register a directory. However, you can write a Servlet that processes all request as they were a request to a directory. A Servlet like this would be about ten lines of code. Also you can try finding a Servlet implementation that implements WebDAV protocol so directory listings and other features would be available as well.